# Sending JSON request POST in android

Tags: android, json, rest

I'm trying to send json post request to : `http://5.101.97.65:3000/en/api/sessions`

**Post Request Structure :**

```
{user: {email: 'value', password: 'value '} }
```

**Response should be like this :**

```
{"success":true Or False,"info":"...","data":{"auth_token":"...."}}
```

For this example normaly it should return true value for "success" key :

```
{"user":{"email":"user@example.com","password":"changeme"}}
```

And this is my code :

```
final String myUrl ="http://5.101.97.65:3000/api/sessions";
        String result = null;
        String params = "{\"user\":{\"email\":\"user@example.com\",\"password\":\"changeme\"}}";
        try {
            restHandler rh = new restHandler();
            result = rh.getResponse(myUrl, 2, params);
            JSONObject rs = new JSONObject(result);
            if (rs.getBoolean("success"))
                return "good";
            else
                return "baad";
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "baaad";
        }
```

The **restHandler** Class (function getResponse only ) :

```
public String getResponse (String url, int method, String params) {
        try {
            // http client
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

            // Checking http request method type
            if (method == 2) {
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                if (params != null)
                {
                    httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                    httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(params, "UTF8"));
                }
                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            } else if (method == 1) {
                // code for httpGet not needed here
            }

            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
            httpClient = null;
            httpEntity = null;
            httpResponse = null;


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }
```

The problem that I'm getting always as result the **HTML code of error page** not even the json response. So what's wrong in my code ?

Comment: I recommend you to use this plugin : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo

Comment: @Abdellah I alreadt have it. didn't helped me too much

Comment: It's you how develop the stuff server side ?

Comment: No I just got this api and I'm workign on it and the curl request work fine  have you check it ?

Comment: yeah i checked with curl but I didn't get the same result as you put in your question `{"success":..`

Comment: do you get the right result with curl?

Comment: @Abdellah check with this again `curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X POST http://5.101.97.65:3000//api/sessions -d "{\"user\":{\"email\":\"user@example.com\",\"password\":\"changeme\"}}"` It works for me

Comment: @Chelbta `<h2>ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken</h2> ..` ?

Comment: @Abdellah the curl work's fine I have try it again it worked and I have sloved the problem check my new post I'm gona write the response.

Comment: @Abdellah can I get you mail [kaouach . Ahmed @ gmail . com]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63956/discussion-between-abdellah-and-chlebta).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that when I send Post Request is always sended as `PlainText` so I have changed this :

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
```

To this :

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

And then I have added :

```
httpPost.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
```

To slove the problem  of `422 unprocessable entity` on the response.

**Final Code (The updated part only)**

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

        // Checking http request method type
        if (method == POST) {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            if (params != null)
            {
                httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                httpPost.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(params));

            }
```